# CCNA Bootcamp with Skyline Advanced Technology Services

Tags: untagged

Have any of you taken a course with [Skyline Advanced Technology Services](http://www.skyline-ats.com/)?  Even better, their [CCNA v2 course](http://www.skyline-ats.com/Corporate/Training/T_CourseDetailClass.php?ClassId=862)?  If so, recommend them, or tell me your horror stories :)

(I know, this looks kind of like an ad for them.  It's not!  I want to know if they're reputable or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a Cisco voice class with Skyline in Chicago a few years ago and it was probably one of the better courses I have taken.  They had decent equipment available considering that the course required two servers, client and phone available for each student.

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I'll even be in the Chicago classroom, so this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Skyline is one of the better training places out there.  That being said don't waste your money or credits on the CCNA courses.

Go out and get the current CCNA set of books by Wendell Odom and study them until you feel confident in it.  Then go through all of the prep and "do you know this already" questions.  If you can pass those you'll be fine for CCNA cert and have more than you'd retain from the course.

[CCNA Certification Library](http://www.ciscopress.com/title/1587201836)

[Cisco CCNA Prep Center](http://forums.cisco.com/eforum/servlet/PrepCenter?page=main)

edit: If you do take the course from Skyline, sign up for one of the ones that has you using Cisco 6500s.  They are a bulk of the cisco cash flow and are a great device to have experience on even if many places are starting to purchase the Nexus line now.  If you understand the 6k's you'll have no issues with the lower level switches.

Comment: I would agree, but the circumstances dictate that I go the boot-camp route.

Thanks!